# Guidance on using validation endpoint of salesforce journey builder custom activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

We are building an SFMC journey builder custom activity where configuration includes 3 screens in a wizard-like structure (Back / Next / Finish). On each screen, we would like to validate the mandatory fields and length validations. We are using react for the frontend and can do all the validations on the frontend but we also see that there is a validation endpoint which gets called when we move from one screen to another and also when the journey is activated.

I am looking for guidance on best practices for this i.e. should the validate endpoint be used for such validations or do they need to be in the frontend logic.In general what else the validation endpoint should have in case of a custom activity.